# how do i check hosts in php?

Tags: php

I want to match by hostname and I can't figure out how,

example: i want to force all links to be from `oi*.tinypic.com` or `i*.tinypic.com`. However people bypass my current validation by using then adding hash at the back of the URL like `.jpg#tinypic`, if i use `stripos()` to prevent abuse on the forum.

also, how do i check it's well formed url, of https or http? I'm using `parse_url()` and doing if `(!$var)` but it sometimes doesn't work for some reason i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parse_url()` on the referer, then use `strpos` only on `host` part.

When `parse_url()` doesn't work, what is the result? `print_r` is your friend.